# Dynamic range to be conditionally formatted based of cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have 2 rows. One is the list of some names. And the second row has a number. I want the first row to be color formatted conditionally based on the value in row 2. So if in row 2 there is 3, then 3 cells in row 1 will get colored. I have written a formula but it is somehow not working:
[image]

Here's the formula:

```
=AND(B$1>=INDEX($B$1:$N$1,MATCH(1E+99,$B$2:B$2)),B$1<(TIME(HLOOKUP(1E+99,$B$2:B$2,1),0,0)+INDEX($B$1:$N$1,MATCH(1E+99,$B$2:B$2))))
```

Thank you

Edit:

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the names are in row 1 and the numbers are in row 2, and that your data starts in column A, use this formula for your conditional format:

```
=COLUMN(A2)-LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER($A2:A2)),$A2:A2)<LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER($A2:A2)),$A2:A2)
```

If your data starts in column B, then this is the conditional format formula you should use:

```
=COLUMN(B2)-LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER($B2:B2)),$B2:B2)-1<LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER($B2:B2)),$B2:B2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works only partially. It is behaving weirdly. First, it starts coloring from the next cell. I want it to color from the same corresponding cell. For eg., if i have 2 in B2, I want B1 and C1 to be colored. Also, sometimes it colors for one extra cell. Don't know why. Thanks!

Comment: @user1778266 Remember, the formula assumes that your data starts in column A.  If your data starts in column B, change all references from `A` to `B` in the formula

Comment: @user1778266 I have edited the answer to show the correct conditional format formula if your data starts in column B.  Note that it also requires the `-1` before `<`

Comment: My data starts from A. But it is still behaving weirdly. I have added screenshots in my question.